# MS ACCESS update with an aggregate function on another table

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am trying to run the below in ms access 2010 and not getting saying "Operation must use an updatable query"

Please some advice on how to solve this without creating a query or temp table.

UPDATE tmp SET non_null_cnt = (SELECT COUNT(id_sec) FROM ESG_Results WHERE asset4_id IS NOT NULL);

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Access is very finicky about subqueries in various contexts - I just try to avoid them, for the most part.  As a workaround, you can try a domain count solution:

```
UPDATE tmp SET non_null_cnt = DCount("id_sec", "ESG_Results", "asset4_id IS NOT NULL");
```

See if that works for you.  You could also write a quick function which uses a recordset solution if you want.